# Midnight Commander Woes: Output while panels are active, and tab completion

Tags: cygwin, midnight-commander

I'm trying out midnight commander (loved Norton back in the day!) and I'm finding two things hard to work out.  I'm curious if there's ways around this or not however.

1) If the panels are active and I issue a command that has a lot of output, it appears to be lost forever.

i.e., if the panels are visible and I cat something (i.e., cat /proc/cpuinfo), that info is gone forever once the panels get redrawn.

Is there anyway to see the output?  I've tried 'ctrl-o', but it appears to just give me a fresh sub-shell and wipes the previous output away.  Pausing after every invocation is a bit irritating, so I'd rather not use that option.

2) Tab completion for commands

When mc is running, it consumes the tab character for switching panels.  Is there any way to get around this so I can still type in paths and what not on the command line?

I'm running cygwin if that matters at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can get tab-completion by pressing ESC then TAB.  You can also get the currently highlighted file/subdir name onto the command line with ESC-ENTER.

As for the pause to view output issue, I use the 'pause after run' option set to 'on dumb terminals', which seems to work reliably for me.

Something I discovered which I REALLY appreciated was the hide/view of hidden files can be toggled by pressing ALT-. (ALT-PERIOD).   Be aware that often the RIGHT ALT key is NOT seen as an ALT key by the system, so you usually need to use Left-ALT-. to toggle this.  I forgot about the Right-ALT weirdness and thought I'd broken mc one day. {sigh} Such a blonde...

Just checked (xev!), I guess the ALT-. toggle is mapped to ALT_L-., and the right ALT key gives an ALT_R keycode... which doesn't match the mc mapping, causing it to not work... now I know why!  Hooray!

Answer (score 0):

If you use Cygwin's [mintty](http://mintty.googlecode.com) terminal, you can use its *Flip Screen* context menu command (or Alt+F12 shortcut) to switch between the so-called alternate screen, where fullscreen applications like *mc* normally run, and the primary screen where output from commands such as *cat* appears.